# Function for same length of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, vector

I want to make a function, which should remake list of vectors of different lengths to list of vectors with the same lengths. I made two functions, but the second one does not work well. 
My code is:
first function (works well)

```
delka<-function(x){
  delky<<-NULL
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    delky[i]<<-length(x[[i]])
  }
}
```

Here I globally made object "delky". Second function is

```
uprava<- function(x){
  stejne<<- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    stejne[[i]]<<-vector(x[[i]], length(max(delky)))
  }
}
```

Where I want to globally make an object "stejne" containing vectors with same lengths. But R answer me an issue

> Error in vector(x[[i]], length(max(delky))) : invalid 'mode' argument

Do you have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the desired behavior. If the vectors in the list are different lengths, what should happen to the shorter ones? (Should the extra spaces be filled in with 0s? with NAs?)

Comment: in `vector()` first argument `mode` should be a string specifying a mode of a vector. see `?vector`

Comment: it doesnt matter what will be in the vectors, zeros or NAs. I can really easy replace NAs by zeros or vice versa. My goal is to find what im doing wrong. Ill try to find out learning more about vector mode argument. Thx for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming @RomanLuštrik is correct about what you are trying to do, you can do this much more directly using the following:

```
lapply(my, `length<-`, max(lengths(my)))
## $a
##  [1] 0.8669645 0.9224072 0.2003480 0.9476093 0.1095652        NA
##  [7]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## 
## $b
##  [1] 0.6679763 0.2742245 0.7726615 0.4247057 0.7274648 0.8218540
##  [7] 0.4874759 0.4764729 0.3958279 0.1653358 0.2331573
## 
## $c
##  [1] 0.71882342 0.92852497 0.75134020 0.53098586 0.17515857
##  [6] 0.04997067 0.70350036         NA         NA         NA
## [11]         NA
##
```

The `lengths` function was relatively recently introduced, so make sure you are running the most recent version of R.

Comment: Thx for great solution, but it does not answer my question. You are so great cause you spent time writing this answer, but Im really looking for what i am doing wrong in my code. My goal isnt just solve this problems, ill have another probles so id like to find what im doing wrong to learn R better. Do you have any idea what i am diong wrong? But once again, really thx for repply.

Comment: @Bobesh then your question belongs on **Code Review**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can work on whole lists at a time, and if you want to pad the shorter vectors with NAs, here's one way.

```
my <- list(a = runif(5),
           b = runif(11),
           c = runif(7))

maxl <- max(sapply(my, length))

sapply(my, FUN = function(x, ml) {
  difference <- ml - length(x)
  c(x, rep(NA, difference))
}, ml = maxl, simplify = FALSE)

$a
 [1] 0.91906470 0.68651070 0.07317576 0.52985130 0.27916889         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA

$b
 [1] 0.86384953 0.79707167 0.88226627 0.91590091 0.03181455 0.86493584 0.89597354 0.80890065 0.92418156 0.72947596 0.13847751

$c
 [1] 0.2576621 0.6512487 0.5806530 0.8782730 0.0262019 0.1000885 0.5245472        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

in another representation

```
sapply(my, FUN = function(x, ml) {
  difference <- ml - length(x)
  c(x, rep(NA, difference))
}, ml = maxl)

               a          b         c
 [1,] 0.91906470 0.86384953 0.2576621
 [2,] 0.68651070 0.79707167 0.6512487
 [3,] 0.07317576 0.88226627 0.5806530
 [4,] 0.52985130 0.91590091 0.8782730
 [5,] 0.27916889 0.03181455 0.0262019
 [6,]         NA 0.86493584 0.1000885
 [7,]         NA 0.89597354 0.5245472
 [8,]         NA 0.80890065        NA
 [9,]         NA 0.92418156        NA
[10,]         NA 0.72947596        NA
[11,]         NA 0.13847751        NA
```

Comment: Thx for great solution, but it does not answer my question. You are so great cause you spent time writing this answer, but Im really looking for what i am doing wrong in my code. My goal isnt just solve this problems, ill have another probles so id like to find what im doing wrong to learn R better. Do you have any idea what i am diong wrong? But once again, really thx for repply.